# Does Doctrine repository's findBy method support Enums?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

On a Symfony 6.0.8 project using Doctrine 2.7.0, I've added some Enums as field types for my entities (I followed this tutorial: https://smaine-milianni.medium.com/use-php-enums-as-doctrine-type-in-symfony-85909aa0a19a) and everything works fine.

What bugs me is that in my repositories, I can filter by these fields with this

```
$qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
$query = $qb->select("e")
    ->where('e.status = :status')
    ->setParameter('status', Status::STATUS_ACCEPTED)
    ;

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

but not this

```
$criterias = array(
    "status" => Status::STATUS_ACCEPTED,
);
$repository->findBy($criterias);
```

Adding `->value` didn't help either. As soon as I try to filter with Enums, it returns an empty set.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If adding `->value` didn't help, it means the condition is not matching in general, in current doctrine `'fieldName' => SomeEnum::SOME_CASE` seems to work just fine as well as hardcoded value. Also check if the DB type matches the enum scalar type (e.g. you don't have string cases, but int column)

Answer (score 0):

`setParameter` works because of [this code](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.12.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L429):

```
// \Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::processParameterValue
if ($value instanceof BackedEnum) {
    return $value->value;
}
```

I can't be sure about why criteria doesn't work in that way, but I think that's because of `\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister::expandParameters` ([here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.12.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php#L1865)). But weird thing that if you would try to pass `->value` that would be int|string, and it should work fine. Please check that `->value` returns a string, that contains in database column.